# Reference to a file error

Tags: applescript

I am trying to execute code from a file but fail to path a correct 
reference and get the following error.

```
Safari got an error: 
Can’t get file "Main:Users:Adrian:Documents:Portfolio:automation:explorer:logic.js" of window 1.
```

**I did try do it like:**

```
tell application "Safari"
    tell window 1
        set current tab to make new tab with properties {URL:"...some"}
        delay 5
        do JavaScript file "Main:Users:Adrian:Documents:logic.js" in current tab
    end tell
end tell
```

**And...**

```
tell application "Safari"
    tell window 1
        set current tab to make new tab with properties {URL:"...some"}
        delay 5
        do JavaScript (file "Main/Users/Adrian/Documents/explorer.js") in current tab
    end tell
end tell
```

The path that I specify is the path I took from coping path from file information (cmd + i)

```
/Users/Adrian/Documents/logic.js
```

**Main** is the hard drive name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `do JavaScript` parameter must be `text`, so you probably have to read the file first. Btw: POSIX paths start always with a slash representing the startup volume unlike the colon separated HFS paths which start with a disk name.

```
set jsText to read "/Users/Adrian/Documents/explorer.js" as «class utf8»
tell application "Safari"
    tell window 1
        set current tab to make new tab with properties {URL:"...some"}
        delay 5
        do JavaScript jsText in current tab
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: thank you a lot, for a good explanation. It did help a lot! :)